# Apple 2 Factor Authentication

Tags: ios, two-factor-authentication

I manage an Apple developer account for my company.  I don't actually have or use an iOS device.  I am being required to accept 2 factor authentication (2 step verification is already enabled) which appears to require me to have a "trusted iOS device".  I don't have one.  What can I do?

Please note that:

1. I access the account from Chrome on my Windows PC.
2. I rarely use the account except to sort out occasional messages from Apple and accept changes to the Terms and Conditions.

Comment: This is a good excuse for the company to get you a new iPad! Do you have access to a Mac?  That can also act as a trusted device.  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915